# MVC Date parameter always null using AJAX (JSONConvert Serialize)

Tags: json, model-view-controller, serialization

Currently working on the passing of view data to controller for MVC via AJAX post request
I noticed that date parameter is always null/default(01/01/0001) when I received it in my controller , I don't know the reason. Can someone shed a light?

My AJAX request is tihs

```
        var details =  @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ param: details }),
        url: "@Url.Action("Index", "PaymentPlan")",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#divPayPlan").html(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error.responseText);
        }
    });
```

My Model is:

```
public class PayPlan{
  
    public virtual int MaxTerms { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime FirstPaymentDate { get; set; }}
```

See this Image [JSON Serialze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neJvP.png)

See my UI [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgdkR.png)

Comment: Can you show how you are setting `details` in your ajax? I mean what's inside the `details` variable

Comment: Hi @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil actually the details contain the Model of View

which is the binding of PayPlan using Html.EditorFor fields

Comment: You can use `string FirstPaymentDate` in `PayPlanViewModel` which will be used for `Html.EditorFor` fields and then convert it to `DateTime FirstPaymentDate` for `PayPlanModel` which you will use to store data in DB. I once faced this problem & I solved it that way.